# cycle() an image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm want to display different image version:

first article: big banner

second: small banner that float to right/left

so, first thing: use cycle() but dont work:

```
= cycle(image_tag(banner_big), image_tag(banner_small)
```

or

```
= image_tag(cycle(banner_big_path, banner_small_path))
```

Only first image is displayed

There's a proper way to make one like that ?

Comment: `cycle()` have to be ran inside a loop within some page, so on each loop cycle it'll return next value, and all values will be on that page simultaneously. Is that you want to achieve?

Comment: So you've got multiple articles on the same page and you want some to display the big image and some to display the small image? Is the value of banner_big_path and banner_small_path different for each article (if so, where does it come from?)

Comment: yes, it's for multiple articles on the same page. An article have different version of illustration with different images namespaced (small_ big_ ...) from carrierwave, but not 'cycled', in my two examples, only the first image (banner_big) is displayed on each articles and it's the only 'cycle' on the page. Small look like /local_uploads/actu/slider/8/banderolle_shenmue-2.jpg & Big /local_uploads/actu/slider/8/big_shenmue-2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that rails is expecting you to call cycle with the same set of strings each time. At the moment you're passing a different pair of strings to each call to cycle, so rails resets the cycle each time. New cycles always start with their first value, hence the result you describe.

Assuming your articles had methods called `small_path`, `big_path`, something like

```
article.send(cycle("big_path","small_path"))
```

Should return alternate image paths.

Comment: Nice one ! so I added =image_tag(actu.send(cycle("big_path","small_path", :name => "pic")), :class => cycle("big", "small", :name => "classpic")) and it look like http://i.imgur.com/NCyl2.png

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `session` facility to store indexes there and use those. For instance:

```
# application_helper.rb
def session_banner_index
  session[:banner_index] || 0
end

def session_banner(*list)
  list[session_banner_index % list.length]
end

# application_controller.rb
def increment_session_banner_index!
  session[:banner_index] = (session[:banner_index] || 0) + 1
end
```

These helper methods approximate the interface you were asking for:

```
 = image_tag(session_banner(banner_big, banner_small))
```