# Using cycle method for the class in an image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, class, cycle

I have a requirement in one of view files,where I have to cycle the class for my image tag. Since it is inside an image tag I'd have to use `<%= data %>` inside the `<%= image_tag %>`.

```
<%= image_tag(room.image_url, class="<%= cycle('room1', 'room2') %>") %>
```

I think we cannot use it that way. <%= %> in side another. if not please correct me.I'm fairly new to Rails.

I found this link here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913550/cycle-an-image-tag

In one of the comments I saw something like this:

```
<%= image_tag(room.image_url, :class => cycle('room1', 'room2')) %>
```

I tried this but its just taking room1 as css everytime. Not alternating between room1 & room2.

I have been working on it from a long time. I would be glad if someone could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it like this:

```
cycle('room1', 'room2', name: 'image')
```

Comment: Why does this work? I can replace the `name: 'image'` with any text in the quotes and it works (stops only taking the first option for the cycle).